# Scrapy applying download_delay to selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am using scrapy with Selenium, here's the spider outline

```
class MySpider(spider.Spider):

    name = "myname"
    start_urls = ["example.com"]

    def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):
         self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
         super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        # ignore response, work with selenium instead
        source = self.driver.get(response.url).page_source
        sel = Selector(text=source)
        # now use xpath/css selectors on sel and yield item
        ...
```

The problem is I was getting 111 Connection Error after a varying number of pages were crawled (sometimes 100, sometimes 200) so I implemented download_delay and autothrottling which is pretty cool.

But selenium doesn't talk to the middleware and I'm not really using the response returned from the middleware. So I will have to implement my own download_delay.

Unfortunately, I know very little about twisted, concurrent programming and the like, so I'm not sure is something which is the equivalent of `time.sleep(secs)` before calling `self.driver.get` would be reasonable (blocking code?).

How do you implement download delays when using scrapy with selenium to parse the responses?

Comment: It seems that time.sleep is anyhow used by selenium for its waits, so it can't be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Support [Explicit](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) and [Implicit](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) Waits. If you think waiting for certain amount of time is enough for your page to be loaded, use:

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(secs)
```

but if you want to wait for a special event (e.g. waiting for a particular element to be loaded) you can do something like:

```
try:
    def find(self.driver):
        dropdown = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a')
        if dropdown:
            return dropdown
        else:
            return False
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, secs).until(find)
except:
    self.driver.quit()
```

Explicit wait can help you to implement `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`. You just need to wait for the element that is loaded the last on the page.

Comment: Selenium waits are not really a replacement for `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`. The `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` is about *waiting X seconds before sending the next page request*. In other words, it is something like a `time.sleep(X)` before calling `driver.get()`.